# (Xamarin.Android) Turn camera picture if the device orientation was landscape

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-camera, textureview

I want to make a Xamarin.Android app where I can capture pictures like the camera...

When I take the picture i have to turn the picture in the correct orientation. So when the orientation was landscape or upside down I want to turn it to portrait...
But I don't know how I can do this.

**Here is my code**

```
 private async void TakePhotoButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _camera.StopPreview();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        builder.SetMessage("Search for faces...");
        builder.SetTitle("Warten");

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.Create();

        dialog.Show();

        byte[] imageBytes;

        var image = _textureView.Bitmap;

        using (var imageStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, imageStream);
            image.Recycle();
            imageBytes = imageStream.ToArray();
        }

        var base64image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

        FaceRecognition faceRecognition = new FaceRecognition();
        var result = faceRecognition.SendPhoto(base64image);

        dialog.Hide();

        _camera.StartPreview();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Android.Content.Res.Orientation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.Orientation/) to get your device orientation, when the orientation was `Landscape`, use [RequestedOrientation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Activity.RequestedOrientation/)  to  request orientation of the activity.

For example  :

```
if (Resources.Configuration.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
{
    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you have to update your `OnSurfaceTextureUpdated` function to this and also alowing screen rotations:

```
public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface)
    {
    var display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;

    if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0)
    {
        _camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
    }

    if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90)
    {
        _camera.SetDisplayOrientation(0);
    }

    if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180)
    {
        _camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
    }

    if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270)
    {
        _camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
    }
}
```